# How to generate a unique ID based on duplicate values in either of two columns?

Tags: r, uniqueidentifier

I am looking to generate a unique ID based on identical values in either of two columns. Specifically, I have the phone numbers and e-mails of customers over a historic period. Therefore, I want to generate a unique ID identifying the customer, even if the customer has changed phone number or e-mail during this time period. The data looks like this:

```
E-mail         Phone      Name
mortena        3076       morten
kaspera        2688       kasper
christoffera   1212       christoffer
mortenb        3076       morten
mortena        3075       morten
kasperb        2688       kasper
christoffera   1213       christoffer
```

And I'd like to produce this result:

```
E-mail         Phone      Name        ID
mortena        3076       morten      1
kaspera        2688       kasper      2
christoffera   1212       christoffer 3
mortenb        3076       morten      1
mortena        3075       morten      1
kasperb        2688       kasper      2
christoffera   1213       christoffer 3
```

Any help is much appreciated!

I've attempted to utilize the code below. However, this seems to create ID's based on identical e-mail and phonenumbers. I am looking to generate a unique ID based on either e-mail or phonenumber.

```
test_data %>% 
  mutate(ID = group_indices_(test_data, .dots=c("E.mail", "Phone")))
```

I expect the script to check through phone numbers and generate a unique ID per unique phone number, and if it can't find any duplicate phone numbers then go through e-mail and do the same thing.

Comment: You could use `df %>% mutate(ID = as.integer(as.factor(Name)))` but this will give slightly different numbers (e.g. `"morten"` will give `ID = 3` and so on, based on the alphabetical ordering of unique `Name`s). The same can be achieved with `df %>% mutate(ID = group_indices(., Name))`. Is the particular order of `ID`s a critical requirement?

Comment: Another option is to use `match`, `match(test_data$Name, unique(test_data$Name))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment above, to reproduce the same `ID` order you need to ensure the proper `factor` level ordering

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ID = as.integer(factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))))
#        E.mail Phone        Name ID
#1      mortena  3076      morten  1
#2      kaspera  2688      kasper  2
#3 christoffera  1212 christoffer  3
#4      mortenb  3076      morten  1
#5      mortena  3075      morten  1
#6      kasperb  2688      kasper  2
#7 christoffera  1213 christoffer  3
```

or with `group_indices`

```
df %>% mutate(ID = group_indices(., factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))))
```

---

If the order of `ID`s doesn't matter you can do

```
df %>% mutate(ID = as.integer(as.factor(Name)))
```

or

```
df %>% mutate(ID = group_indices(., Name))
```

In these cases, the order of `ID` is determined by the alphabetical order of unique `Name`s (rather than by their occurrence).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text = "E-mail         Phone      Name
mortena        3076       morten
kaspera        2688       kasper
christoffera   1212       christoffer
mortenb        3076       morten
mortena        3075       morten
kasperb        2688       kasper
christoffera   1213       christoffer", header = T)
```